# How to use a SwitchPreference to create a setting for light/night mode

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

For my app I am using SharedPreferences to create a setting that allows the user to switch between light and dark theme when using it.  My problem is every time I load up the app and turn on the setting nothing happens and how to make my app switch between light and dark theme using a SwitchPreference using multiple activities.

For context I am building an app that is connected to Firestore that allows users to add TV show data from the Recycler View list.

I have tried looking for documentation on Google and watching videos online to see if I can find any similarity to my issue, but every time I do there is like 50 different ways of doing so.

This is my activity for the RecyclerView List and some of the SharedPreferences:

```
    override fun onResume(){
        super.onResume()
        
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        val isDarkTheme = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("night",false)

        if (!isDarkTheme) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            editor.putBoolean("night",false)
            editor.apply()
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            editor.putBoolean("night",true)
            editor.apply()
        }

        recyclerViewTV = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewShows)
        recyclerViewTV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        data = ArrayList<TV>()

        tvAdapter = TVAdapter(data)
        recyclerViewTV.adapter = tvAdapter

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        db.collection("ProjectTVShows")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    var show = document.getString("name")
                    var direct = document.getString("director")
                    var view = document.getString("viewership")
                    data.add(TV(show, direct, view))

                    Log.d("MY DEBUG", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
                    Log.d("MY DEBUG", "show => $show")
                    Log.d("MY DEBUG", "direct => $direct")
                    Log.d("MY DEBUG", "view => $view")
                }
                tvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w("MY DEBUG", "Error getting documents.", exception)
            }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolmenu, menu)

        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.getItemId()) {
            R.id.add_shows-> {
                val intent = Intent(this@TVShowListActivity, AddShowActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                true
            }

            R.id.settings->{
                val intent = Intent(this@TVShowListActivity, SettingsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                true
            }

            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }}
```

This is my UserPreferenceFragment:

```
class UserPreferenceFragment: PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

This is my preference layout for the light/dark mode setting
[image: preference layout]

This is my preference layout in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:defaultValue="false"
        app:key="night"
        app:summary="Toggle between light and dark mode"
        app:title="@string/light_settings" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Put you resource editor in Code mose and post text of xml file.

Comment: In  onResume when night is false you put again night as false. And if true you put true again. That makes no sence. You should only read the value of the switch. Not try to change it. Just check if you get the right value of the switch

Comment: I put in the xml code

Comment: Can you explain what you mean that I put night as false again and night as true again.

Comment: I already did that. If you dont agree tell us what that code does according to you.

Comment: What the code is suppose to do is make the theme turn into dark mode when night is true and when false it is suppose to not turn the theme into dark mode, but it does not do that.

Comment: Thats what i thought. And i already told you why it does not do so.